# How to get subs/sups for figures but not letters?

Tags: fontspec

I am playing with a font (found [here](https://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/sorts-mill-goudy)) that has sups/subs defined for figures but not for letters.  If I don't enable them, I don't get them:

[image: No proper sups/subs for figures]

But if I `\usepackage{realscripts}` to enable them, I lose the ability to use letters as sub/superscripts at all:

[image: with package realscripts]

Is there a way for me to get the subs/sups figures while retaining the ability to use letters in sub/superscripts?  Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{OFLGoudyStM}[
    Extension      = .otf,
    Ligatures      = {Common, TeX},
    ItalicFont     = OFLGoudyStM-Italic]
\usepackage{realscripts}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l}
  M\textsuperscript{abc0123456789def} \\
  M\textsubscript{abc0123456789def}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `realscripts` is only useful if *all* the glyphs you need to superscript or subscript are drawn specifically in the font. There's no way within XeTeX of detecting whether a given font feature will affect a particular glyph (or run of glyphs), so you can't even know until you typeset the document and inspect the output.

Well, in some cases you could make a box and compare its size before and after setting the font feature, but that method probably has edge-cases that would cause it to be occasionally unreliable.

Another option might be to inspect the contents of the `\textsuperscript` argument and branch according to the input. I.e.,

```
\textsuperscript{a1} -> 
\textsuperscript{a}\textsuperscript{1} ->
\fakesuperscript{a}\realsuperscript{1}
```

But this would look terrible because `a` and `1` would look very different, so it'd be better to use `\fakesuperscript` (i.e., don't like `realscripts`) in this case.

Comment: I think I need `\textsuperscript` defined as `realscripts` does to get proper automatic behavior for footnotes.  If I call `realscripts`, is there some way for me to _manually_ specify a superscript with sups disabled?  Say `\textsuperscript{1}` but `\mysuperscript{a}`, where `mysuperscript` has sups off?  (You just answered this, I didn't know about `\fakesuperscript`.)

Comment: Of course. I wrote it in my answer already: `\fakesuperscript`. There's an unfortunate typo in the documentation, though. The first sentence of section 2 should read "The OLD commands are defined in starred form (e.g., \textsubscript*) for cases where the new commands are not appropriate.".